# How to see the olddir after mount --bind olddir newdir?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, debian-squeeze, debian-wheezy

In my debian 7:

```
$ pwd
/home/freestyler

$ mkdir old new
# mount --bind old new
```

then

```
$ mount
/dev/cciss/c0d0p9 on /home/freestyler/new type ext4(rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

I can only see the `/dev/cciss/c0d0p9`, which is not the same as `/home/freestyler/old`

How can I get the original olddir path?

In debian 6:

the `mount` outpt the olddir path well:

```
 $ mount

/home/freestyler/old on /home/freestyler/new type none (rw,bind)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, <strike>don't have an answer for you but</strike> here is the bug report:

[mount: Bind mounts not shown as such in mount output](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=691151)

I was really curious about a way around this so I grabbed the debian 7 live cd and started playing around. I eventually came to this post:

> Note that /etc/mtab is only useful here if it's a text file maintained by mount. Some distributions set up /etc/mtab as a symbolic link to /proc/mounts instead; /proc/mounts is mostly equivalent to /etc/mtab but does have a few differences, one of which is not tracking bind mounts.
>
> One piece of information that is retained by the kernel, but not shown in /proc/mounts, is when a mount point only shows a part of the directory tree on the mounted filesystem. In practice this mostly happens with bind mounts:
>
> > mount --bind /mnt/one/sub /mnt/partial
>
> In /proc/mounts, the entries for /mnt/one and /mnt/partial have the same device, the same filesystem type and the same options. The information that /mnt/partial only shows the part of the filesystem that's rooted at /sub is visible in the per-process mount point information in /proc/$pid/mountinfo (column 4). Entries there look like this:
>
> > 12 34 56:78 / /mnt/one rw,relatime - ext3 /dev/foo rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
> >     12 34 56:78 /sub /mnt/partial rw,relatime - ext3 /dev/foo rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered

And in my testing, you may be able to extract the information you need by using:

```
root@debian:~# cat /proc/1/mountinfo 
14 24 0:13 / /sys rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - sysfs sysfs rw
15 24 0:3 / /proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - proc proc rw
16 24 0:5 / /dev rw,relatime - devtmpfs udev rw,size=10240k,nr_inodes=126630,mode=755
17 16 0:10 / /dev/pts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime - devpts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
18 24 0:14 / /run rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=102704k,mode=755
20 24 11:0 / /lib/live/mount/medium ro,noatime - iso9660 /dev/sr0 ro
21 24 7:0 / /lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs ro,noatime - squashfs /dev/loop0 ro
22 23 0:16 / /lib/live/mount/overlay rw,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw
23 24 0:17 / /lib/live/mount/overlay rw,noatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw,mode=755
24 1 0:18 / / rw,relatime - aufs aufs rw,si=993d359391edfb38,noxino
25 18 0:19 / /run/lock rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=5120k
26 18 0:20 / /run/shm rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=205400k
27 15 0:21 / /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw
29 24 0:18 / /bindmount rw,relatime - aufs aufs rw,si=993d359391edfb38,noxino
30 24 0:18 /root/old /root/new rw,relatime - aufs aufs rw,si=993d359391edfb38,noxino
```

From: [List only bind mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18067)

You can also use `cat /proc/$$/mountinfo` or if in an application, you can use the local applications PID.

In the comments of the other question, another possible option to use is `findmnt |fgrep [` or if you are just visually checking, just `findmnt` and you can read down the source column to see the bind mounts listed.

```
root@debian:~# findmnt | fgrep [
└─/root/new                                  aufs[/root/old] aufs         rw,relatime,si=993d359391edfb38,noxino
```

Comment: Updated with a possible workaround for you

Comment: Great, it works for me.